# Monaco auto completion can't list symbols

Tags: monaco-editor

So, I am using Monaco Editor and creating my custom language. I am using the `monaco.languages.registerCompletionItemProvider` for auto completion for my language. I can't seem to figure auto how to list my symbols in the auto completion list. It works well when I want a list of words for auto completion but it does not work when I want a list of symbols. So, I want the
"value" variable to be listed as the "label", instead of "k" listed as the label, but it can't because they are symbols. Are there any workarounds?

```
    var op = new Map([])
    op.set('and', '∧');
    op.set('or', '∨');
    op.set('implies','→');
    op.set('not', '¬');
    op.set('forall','∀');
    op.set('exists','∃');
    op.set('turnstile','⊢');
    let operators = ['and', 'or', 'implies', 'not', 'forall', 'exists','turnstile'];

monaco.languages.registerCompletionItemProvider('logium', {
            provideCompletionItems: (model, position) => {
                const suggestions = [
                     ...operators.map(k => {
                        let value = getByKey(op, k);
                         return {
                             label : k,
                             kind: monaco.languages.CompletionItemKind.Function,
                             insertText: value
                         };
                     }),   
                    ];
                return {suggestions: suggestions};
            }
        })
```

Here is a picture of how it looks when I have "k" as my "label":

[image: Here is a picture of how it looks when I have "k" as my "label":]

And here is a picture of how it look when I have "value" as my "label":

[image: And here is a picture of how it look when I have "value" as my "label":]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't forget this is auto completion, which means it completes what the user already typed. If you have single letter suggestions and one letter was also typed, which doesn't match any of the suggestions, then no suggestion is shown. You have to show the values which the user can type, not the values you want to insert instead.

Comment: Okay, so there are no way of listing words/symbol, that are not a substring of the word I am typing in? Any workaround?

Comment: I haven't tried but maybe the `filterText` member of the suggestion item can be used here? Set this to the plain text and use the symbols in the label. Might work.

Comment: Thank you so much! It actually worked. I have been sitting with this for hours and hours.